# Wrappers For Performing SQL Transactions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make my ASP.NET MVC application use transactions for all database operations, to ensure safety when there are multiple users. To do this, I have created static methods in my `DbContext` class that take `Action`s or `Func`s as parameters, wrap them in `using` blocks for a new instance of `DbContext` and then a `DbContextTransaction`, and then execute the `Action` or `Func`.

Here are the transaction methods:

```
public static void PerformTransaction(
    Action<SlideDbContext, IList<Slide>> action,
    IList<Slide> slides)
{
    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                action(slideDbContext, slides);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void PerformTransaction(
    Action<SlideDbContext, Slide> action,
    Slide slide)
{
    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                action(slideDbContext, slide);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void PerformTransaction(
    Action<SlideDbContext, int> action,
    int id)
{
    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                action(slideDbContext, id);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void PerformTransaction(
    Action<SlideDbContext, Section> action,
    Section section)
{
    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                action(slideDbContext, section);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Answer PerformTransactionForAnswer(
    Func<SlideDbContext, int, Answer> func,
    int slideId)
{
    Answer answer = null;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                answer = func(slideDbContext, slideId);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    return answer;
}

public static IList<Answer> PerformTransactionForAnswers(
    Func<SlideDbContext, int, IList<Answer>> func,
    int slideId)
{
    IList<Answer> answers = null;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                answers = func(slideDbContext, slideId);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    return answers;
}

public static bool PerformTransactionForBool(
    Func<SlideDbContext, int, bool> func,
    int slideId)
{
    var didSucceed = false;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                didSucceed = func(slideDbContext, slideId);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    return didSucceed;
}

public static Role PerformTransactionForRole(
    Func<SlideDbContext, int, Role> func,
    int roleId)
{
    Role role = null;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                role = func(slideDbContext, roleId);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    return role;
}

public static IList<Role> PerformTransactionForRoles(
    Func<SlideDbContext, IList<Role>> func)
{
    IList<Role> roles = null;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                roles = func(slideDbContext);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    return roles;
}

public static Section PerformTransactionForSection(
    Func<SlideDbContext, int, Section> func,
    int sectionId)
{
    Section section = null;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                section = func(slideDbContext, sectionId);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    return section;
}

public static IList<Section> PerformTransactionForSections(
    Func<SlideDbContext, IList<Section>> func)
{
    IList<Section> sections = null;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                sections = func(slideDbContext);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    return sections;
}

public static Slide PerformTransactionForSlide(
    Func<SlideDbContext, Slide> func)
{
    Slide slide = null;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                slide = func(slideDbContext);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    return slide;
}

public static Slide PerformTransactionForSlide(
    Func<SlideDbContext, int, Slide> func,
    int slideId)
{
    Slide slide = null;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                slide = func(slideDbContext, slideId);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
    return slide;
}

public static async Task<Slide> PerformTransactionForSlideAsync(
    Func<SlideDbContext, int, Task<Slide>> func,
    int slideId)
{
    Slide slide = null;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                slide = await func(slideDbContext, slideId);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    return slide;
}

public static Slide PerformTransactionForSlideConditional(
    Func<SlideDbContext, Func<Slide, bool>, Slide> func,
    Func<Slide, bool> conditional)
{
    Slide slide = null;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                slide = func(slideDbContext, conditional);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    return slide;
}

public static IList<Slide> PerformTransactionForSlides(
    Func<SlideDbContext, IList<Slide>> func)
{
    IList<Slide> slides = null;

    using (var slideDbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction =
            slideDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                slides = func(slideDbContext);
                slideDbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    return slides;
}
```

Here are some examples of how these are used:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title")] Role role)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(role);
    }

    SlideDbContext.PerformTransaction(Create, role);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var role =
        SlideDbContext.PerformTransactionForRole(Get, id.Value);

    if (role == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(role);
}

private static void Create(SlideDbContext slideDbContext, Role role)
{
    slideDbContext.Roles.Add(role);
}

private static Role Get(SlideDbContext slideDbContext, int id)
{
    return slideDbContext.Roles.Find(id);
}
```

Is there something I should be doing different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple overloads for different type of parameters but those parameters come from *outside* and you just pass-through. I see two different scenarios:

- Use generics to have only a couple of methods.
- Do not use parameters at all (for when you want to write body directly inside the lambda).

Another thing: you're swallowing the exception and it will make debugging a nightmare. I'm usually against catching `Exception` but in this case I think it's right (and you may simplify code little bit):

I simplified names little bit, for example I do not think that - in this context - `dbContextTransaction` is more readable than simply `transaction`.

```
public static void PerformTransaction<T>(Action<SlideDbContext, T> action, T items)
{
    using (var dbContext = new SlideDbContext())
    using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            action(dbContext, items);

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            dbContext.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

That's all, just one method. You might also want to add an overload without any parameter (when *business* logic is simple and in the right place the Controller logic is pretty straightforward).

When you need a return value the prototype may be something like this:

```
TResult PerformTransaction<TParameter, TResult>(
    Func<SlideDbContext, TParameter, TResult> action, TParameter parameter)
```

Note: not every error is unrecoverable, sometimes waiting or trying again will *solve* the problem. Especially if you're using SQL Server take a look to [Know when to retry or fail when calling SQL Server from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24041062/1207195)

Comment: Something like `TResult PerformTransaction<TParameter,
 TResult>(Func<SlideDbContext, TParameter, TResult> action, TParameter parameter)`.

Comment: I figured it out right after I posted my comment. Have it working perfectly now.